# object reference compiling error

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private static void runantc_OutputDataReceived(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)  
        {
            // Collect the sort command output.
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                ProcoutputTextBlock.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ProcoutputTextBlock.Text += outLine.Data; }, null));
            }
        }
```

Hi, in the above code i am having errors @`ProcoutputTextBlock` Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WpfApplication1.Window1.ProcoutputTextBlock'

and @ `() => { ProcoutputTextBlock.Text += outLine.Data; }, null`
Error 2 Method  name expected

can anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcoutputTextBlock` is an instance property. You are accessing instance property from static method `runantc_OutputDataReceived`.

To resolve this remove `static` from `runantc_OutputDataReceived` declaration.

To fix the second issue, remove the second argument `null`. Like this:

```
ProcoutputTextBlock.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ProcoutputTextBlock.Text += outLine.Data; }));
```

or

```
ProcoutputTextBlock.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { ProcoutputTextBlock.Text += outLine.Data; }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is `static`, which means that it requires a reference to an instance of the class in order to access any instance members. Since I'm assuming that `ProcoutputTextBlock` is a `TextBlock` on your window, it needs an instance in order to access it.

The other option is making the function non-static, but since you don't show how this event handler is being attached, I don't know if that's a viable option for you.